# Views with two content type and different fields in one table

Tags: views

I've got these two content types, A (2014) and B (2015),  I'm tryging to combine in a view but  content A needs field to view node and content B to edit node,

The view show the fields but it show both options edit and view for all contents.

My actual view
[image: my actual view]

The view I would like to do
[image: Planing to do]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question; could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Basically is how to display a field with a condition if content type is A display view link and if content type is B display edit link..

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  If you want to give more information you are supposed to edit your question. This site is not meant as a forum, so don't expect comments to be seen by users judging if your problem is worth their time.

Answer (score 1):

For things like this I use [Views Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional).
Work with the replacement variables and hide unused content.

Comment: Nugorra,  this module save my day, I manage to do this with Views Conditional, working pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Views Conditonal solved my problem

if content type A

```
<a href="node/[nid]/edit">2015.................................[edit_node]<span class="read"></span></a> <span class="read" style="margin-left:100px; text-align:right">[percentage]</span>
```

if content type B

```
<a href="node/[nid]">2014................................[view_node]<span class="read"></span></a>
```